# Enable Windows Auth and disable Forms auth on Admin folder

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication, iis-8

Just moved a site from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2012 and having difficulty restricting access to the Admin directory.  In the older version of IIS, all I needed to do was disable anon access to that folder.  In IIS8, I have:

- Anonymous Authentication:  Disabled
- ASP.NET Impersonation:  Disabled
- Basic Authentication:  Disabled
- Forms Authentication:  Enabled
- Windows Authentication:  Enabled

This gives me an Alert that says:

> Challenge-based and login redirect-based authentication cannot be used simultaneously.

Which I find completely reasonable.  However, I am trying to disable "Forms Authentication" and the next Alert says:

> This feature has been locked and is read-only

How can I force an ASP.NET site's admin directory (only that directory) to require Windows Authentication?

Comment: As this seems a general overview of ASP.Net, I'd mention that some of these settings will not have any affect on an ASP.Net MVC application.

Comment: @ErikPhilips - What do you mean by "won't have any effect"?  They will all have some effect depending on various situations.  No, FormsAuthentication won't have any effect on a site using ASP.NET Identity (it removes the FormsAuth module), but other versions will.

Comment: Is the admin folder a virtual directory / have you tried making it one?

Comment: Tried both ways.  It doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your folder is under the same IIS web app (which apparently is) you can't use 2 different kinds of authentication. You need to have 2 separate IIS apps or to have sub-applications (which I think also implies virtual directories).

In other words, you can't have both *Win Auth* and *Forms Auth* enabled at the same time for the same IIS app, with managed pipeline mode set to *Integrated*, in IIS 7+

**Update** After searching through my bookmarks:

---

I tried the ideas from this article, but I could not get it to work: http://mvolo.com/iis-70-twolevel-authentication-with-forms-authentication-and-windows-authentication/
However it might give you more insight or ideas.

My scenario was simpler, I needed Windows and Forms auth for the entire app.

I also had an admin section and I eventually ended up putting the admin in a totally separate web app, that runs under a subdomain. Both apps were running in IIS 7.5 with integrated mode (admin windows auth enabled and the rest of the app was Forms Auth enabled).

Comment: Would it work with classic?  Is that my best option or should I work to split admin out to separate app (admin.mysite.com)?

Comment: I'm not sure about classic, it was used in IIS 6.0 and I did not used that mode, even less for this scenario. At the moment it is considered deprecated.

Comment: I would say yes, it think is much less trouble and the fastest solution if you don't have any restrictions on the server. In the end it matters most to get the job done.

Comment: That's probably what I'll do as well.  It shouldn't be too bad.  Thx

Answer (score 2):

I believe you just need to make your admin folder it's own application root, then you can do what you want.

- From IIS Manager > Sites > {Your Website} > admin folder, right click and choose 'Convert to Application'
- Accept the default settings for the application (you can change if you wish)
- Click on the IIS Manager > Sites > {Your Website} > admin folder, drill down into Authentication, and choose Disable from the right menu.

An image where admin is not it's own app:

[image]

Make it's own app:

[image]